# Why tlmgr has a verify_checksum issue?

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I have a Docker image

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y texlive-xetex \
    texlive-lang-french texlive-fonts-extra texlive-science \
    latexmk git python3
```

From which I would like to install `latexindent`. The issue is that I cannot use tlmgr:

```
root@fba0091062ef latex 
$ tlmgr option repository ctan
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf
tlmgr: running in usermode, did you call `tlmgr init-usertree'?

root@fba0091062ef latex 
$ tlmgr init-usertree

root@fba0091062ef latex 
$ tlmgr update --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

Why do I get this issue?

Comment: Note that the tlmgr provided by debian cannot be used to update texlive or install packages. They want you to use apt for that (you might want to use apt-file to figure out which debian package provides latexindent)

Comment: I got it and I guess to gave me the right answer

Comment: Could you provide an answer to your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved in the comments; the OP has been encouraged to self-answer